# Updating same Instance in two distinct component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react library, I wanted to share same Instance in both places of MyComponent, basically I thought Click Me in anyone of the compoent will update  `<p>{myInstance.myProperty}</p>` in both places since I passed same instance in App, but both of the Component are getting updated in isolated manner. Can someone explain why? Thanks in Advance

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function MyCustomPrototype() {
  this.myProperty = 0;
}

MyCustomPrototype.prototype.handleClick = function () {
  this.myProperty += 1;
};

function MyComponent(prop) {
  const [myInstance, setMyInstance] = useState(prop.myCust);

  function handleClick() {
    myInstance.handleClick();
    setMyInstance(Object.create(myInstance, {
      constructor: {
        value: MyCustomPrototype,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
      },
    }));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{myInstance.myProperty}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}



function App() {
  let myCust1 = new MyCustomPrototype();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent myCust={myCust1} />
      <MyComponent myCust={myCust1} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I thought Click Me in anyone of the compoent will update  `<p>{myInstance.myProperty}</p>` in both places since I passed same instance in App, but both of the Component are getting updated in isolated manner.

[image]

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components

Comment: Did you read about contexts?

Comment: Yes i did, I wanted to see, If I can follow something like Factory design pattern, or isolate hooks from component. Basically give other developers flexibility to override the base prototype function, say for the example for a given case other developers do not want the setMyInstance or     props.setMyCust (as mention in below answer) to get executed immediately, after props.myCust.handleClick();. Since I used it inside component definition now it has become very srtict. Can someone help how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Because each component is using its own local state.  It sounds like you instead want a single top-level state in the parent component.  For example:

```
function App() {
  const [myCust, setMyCust] = useState(new MyCustomPrototype());

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent myCust={myCust} setMyCust={setMyCust} />
      <MyComponent myCust={myCust} setMyCust={setMyCust} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then `MyComponent` would just use the value and setter function provided to it:

```
function MyComponent(props) {

  function handleClick() {
    props.myCust.handleClick();
    props.setMyCust(Object.create(props.myCust, {
      constructor: {
        value: MyCustomPrototype,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
      },
    }));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.myCust.myProperty}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is generally referred to as "lifting state up".  When a single state should be shared by multiple sibling components, that state would belong to the parent component and provided to the sibling components as props.

Other options also include `useContext` to create a shared state among a hierarchy of components, or using an external state management system like Redux.

Comment: Thanks David, I was able to understand it better.

Comment: Additionally I wanted to ask, can this answer be extended to answer above comment,
"If I can follow something like Factory design pattern, or isolate hooks from component. Basically give other developers flexibility to override the base prototype function, say for the example for a given case other developers do not want the setMyInstance or props.setMyCust (as mention in below answer) to get executed immediately, after props.myCust.handleClick();. Since I used it inside component definition now it has become very srtict. Can someone help how can I achieve this".